# kubernetes version up with other components

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade

I've read the official document which describes how to upgrade the Kubernetes.

But, there should be other problems caused by 3rd party softwares such as the admission controller engine, cni, storage plugins, and many other uncountable sw packages.

If I upgrade kubernetes's version, there must be errors since kyverno (installed it a long time ago) version constraints and other 3rd party software that I didn't recognize.

I have no idea how to upgrade my Kubernetes cluster (this is on-premise) and how to control and update all the add-ons.

How do you upgrade your "production" cluster, with all the other dependencies not to disturb the working of this cluster

Is there any way? I really want to know about that.

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version that supports 3rd party software. In most cases, you are likely to encounter errors in more latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to keep everything up-to-date rather than trying to upgrade all at once later.

You need to be subscribed to the release notes of each component you have installed in the cluster and monitor changes. Many security issues are fixed for most components, and it can be a trigger to initiate an upgrade.

Another thing is deprecation notices, you need to monitor them and plan an upgrade in advance.

Last but not least - you usually have the development/staging cluster where you can test everything, including the upgrade itself. In that case, you know what could go wrong and prepare a proper upgrade plan.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have one question.
Does "up-to-date" mean, not only being "up-to-date" for all the components but also being "up-to-date" kubernetes itself?

Comment: It depends on the capacity of your team. Usually, it's safe to be one stable version behind, just in case anything critical happens. But if you have enough power to test everything on the development environment, I don't see any reason not to keep the cluster updated.

Comment: thanks for your answer. All questions that I have are resolved now!